# Как занести данные из БД в массив?

Tags: php, mysql

В базе данных есть таблица цветов с тремя столбцами R, G и B. Нужно данные из столбцов R, G, B занести в массив. 
Данные из БД выбираю таким образом:

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT R, G, B FROM fs_595c") or die(mysql_error());
$myrow = mysql_fetch_array($result);
```

Нужно, чтобы массив выглядел так:

```
$colors = array(
    array(254, 145, 154),
    array(153, 145, 188),
    array(153, 90, 145),
    array(255, 137, 92)
);
```

Помогите пожалуйста!

Comment: а что вы получаете сейчас?

Comment: @splash58, я пробовал так выводить, но это совсем не то: $ta = mysql_query("SELECT sRGB FROM fs_595c"); while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($ta)){ 
   $colors = array(
    array($row),
    
);
 }

Comment: вы лучше в текст вопроса выведите дамп $myrow

Comment: @x_decimo_x И в любом случае, т.к. колонка у вас одна у вас в массиве будет так же одна колона, что бы разить значение на отдельные элементы надо выполнить дополнительную работу, зависящую от содержимого той колонки в БД

Comment: @Mike вы правы, спасибо. Сейчас изменю вопрос

Comment: Прям как вы хотите и должно получаться в `$myrow`. Нет?

Comment: @x_decimo_x тогда `$colors=array(); while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result,MYSQL_NUM)) $colors[]=$row;`

Comment: А почему не fetch_all, и вперед?

Comment: Лучший способ использовать PDO/mysqli. Так как  mysql_* уже не поддерживается.  PDO/mysqli так же имеет функцию fetchAll/fetch_all которая делает ровно то что вы хотите без плясок.

Comment: @splash58 Как не странно этот функционал только в PDO/mysqli  добавили. Сам только глянул в шоке был. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Подойдет?

```
$result = mysql_query("SELECT R, G, B FROM fs_595c") or die(mysql_error());
$colors=array(); 
while($row=mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    $colors[] = array_values($row);
}
var_dump($colors);
```

Comment: Ответ правильный, но почему нет информации о том что лучше mysql_* не использовать?

Comment: данная информация размещена в официальной  документации ( о том что, данное расширение устарело, начиная с версии PHP 5.5.0, и будет удалено в будущем)